# Maintaining JMX connections and load on Remote MBeanServer and JVM

Tags: java, performance, jmx

In my application I creating and maintaining Multiple connections with Remote JVM's MBeanServer. 
I want to pool these connections. But not sure if they put any load on Remote MBeanServer.

I want to know 
Do maintaining the idle rmi JMX connections with Remote JVM MBean server puts any Load on Remote JVMs?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the actual JMX remoting protocol. **JMX/RMI** is actually quite chatty and spins up connection checking threads. **JMXMP** is more efficient, but you're still going to see some accumulating overhead for additional connections, so it will be a trade-off between resource utilization and the cost of establishing new (or sharing) connections.

Can you elaborate on why you want to pool ?

**==== Update ====**

You can use [Apache Commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/). Create an instance of [GenericKeyedObjectPool](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPool.html).The [PoolableObjectFactory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/pool/PoolableObjectFactory.html) implementation should wrap the [JMXConnectorFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXConnectorFactory.html) and you can create a compound key class that contains the [JMXServiceURL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXServiceURL.html) and the credentials to use when borrowing a connection. The object factory can then decompose the key on the [borrow](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPool.html#addObject%28java.lang.Object%29) call, and on the [activate](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/pool/PoolableObjectFactory.html#activateObject%28java.lang.Object%29) call, acquire the authenticated connection.

The actual pooled object should be some sort of wrapper since you will need to create a "disconnected" instance in the makeObject call (and there is no such thing in standard JMX remoting) and then "connect" it on activate if it is not connected already.

Comment: well, i can if it counts :) I have to deal with exactly the same situation - pooling of JMX connections. Or maybe not pooling per se, but caching/persisting of them between client calls. The reason? My application does quite a lot of monitoring of arbitrary number of components via JMX. It does so by polling, so every couple of seconds it requires a JMX connection in order to get the latest status of the component. Connection for each component would require its own set of credentials and configuration. So it would be nice to not have to create a new connection per component every "n" seconds.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising, I will have a look. This made me think though... From JMX point of view, is the idea really to keep the established JMX connections or rather keep a reference to the MBean themselves? If I connect to a MBeans server, get a some MBeans out of it and then keep a reference to them, isn't that how JMX is supposed to be used?

Comment: I have the exact same requirement. Did the Apache Commons Pool work out for you? Is there an equivalent pool in Guava I could use?